# "30 miles to the gallon"

Tags: articles

The 13th entry of "to" in [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/to_1)：

> used to show a quantity or rate
>
> > There are 2.54 centimetres to an inch.
> >
> > This car does 30 miles to **the** gallon.

I'm wondering why the second example is used with **the**, not **a**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["130 yen to the dollar" VS "130 yen to a dollar"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177833/130-yen-to-the-dollar-vs-130-yen-to-a-dollar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"<This car> does 30 miles to the gallon" is an informal idiom.  In this case, "the gallon" is not a specific gallon.

"<This car> gets 30 miles per gallon" is a more formal idiom with the same meaning.

"Given a gallon of gas, <this car> will go 30 miles" is a less common way of saying the same thing.  In this case, the choice between "a" and "the" is based on whether you have a specific gallon of gas in mind.  If someone just put a gallon of gas in the car, you would say "the gallon".  If you are speaking about the car's gas mileage in general, you would say "a gallon".

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought _the gallon_ here was not specific.

Comment: Actually, your impression was correct.  I have clarified my answer, in response to your comment.

Comment: I think "the gallon" refers, not to a specific gallon, but to a specific unit of measure.  <This car> gets 30 miles per the "unit of measure known as a" gallon.

Comment: Can I say "there are 2.54 centimetres to the inch."? @Jim

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng- Yes, nobody would have any problems with that usage, but "*per* inch" is probably more common.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a consensus by usage, except that *the* is preferred to *a*.

[image: Google Books Ngram showing higher counts for "to the gallon" vs. "to a gallon"]
<sup>Source: [Google Books Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20a%20gallon%2Cto%20the%20gallon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3)</sup>

Either one is acceptable, but searching for usage *in context* shows a different pattern. [to the gallon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20the%20gallon%22) is primarily associated with the ratio of miles to gallons:

> The car does 30 miles to the gallon.

But [to a gallon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20a%20gallon%22) is primarily associated with addition or additives:

> This adds 40 cents to a gallon of gas.

When in doubt, do what I did. Plug the concept into a search engine and see the context.

Comment: Why not just look for **“miles** to the/a gallon?” [The difference is even more striking](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miles+to+the+gallon%2Cmiles+to+a+gallon&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: "Miles per gallon" [beats them both](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miles+to+the+gallon%2Cmiles+to+a+gallon%2Cmiles+per+gallon&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).