# "130 yen to the dollar" VS "130 yen to a dollar"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I saw this sentence in the dictionary on my phone(so I can't get a link to it here):

> We're only getting 130 yen to **the** dollar at the moment.

I'm wondering why the definite article '**the**' is being used instead of indefinite article '**a**'? Can we instead say: *We're only getting 130 yen to **a** dollar at the moment*?

I've also seen other examples in which '**the**' is used instead of '**a**':

> The car will do over 40 miles to **the** gallon.
>
> The scale of your map is one inch to **the** mile.

However, I did see an example in which '**a**' is used instead of **'the'**:

> There are just over four and a half litres to **a** gallon.

Can someone help to explain why sometimes **'a'** is used and sometimes **'the'** is used? Or they are just interchangeable in those scenarios?

Comment: "a dollar" is a more general term for 1USD, But here the dollar could be 1CAD or 1AUD. Even here i used "the dollar" in my comment because i know which dollar i am talking about. You can search about "definite and indefinite article in sentences"

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they're interchangeable --- as a native speaker (western US) I would only use:

> We're only getting 130 yen to **the** dollar. (not 'to a dollar')
>   
>  There are just over four and a half liters to **a** gallon. (not 'to the gallon')

I'm less sure about the middle examples. Probably I would say both of them with 'per':

> The car will do over 40 miles **per** gallon.
>   
>  The scale of your map is one inch **per** mile.

Sorry I can't come up with a good reason for these different usage patterns.  I'm not sure there is a good reason.  I just think of "{currency} to the {currency}" as a standard phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first example, I believe the use of the definite article is correct as it involves the specific value of "the dollar" as currency at that specific time. Thank you